# MySQL upgrade - dump/load vs. alter table

Tags: linux, mysql

Upgrading MySQL 5.1->5.5, all InnoDB, 500GB data, linux.

To rebuild the tables/indexes for 5.5, I can either dump and load everything, or run `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE=innodb` on every table (see [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rebuilding-tables.html)).

MySQL recommends the dump and load method
[here
(second paragraph)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) as does Percona [here](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/upgrading_guide_51_55.html#before-starting-full-backup).

I completely understand the necessity of a good backup, but I will have a clean and reliable storage snapshot serving that purpose. Also, dump/load takes much much longer and requires extra disk space and I/Os.

**Is there any other good reason to prefer the dump/load method?**

(same question as this one, but dealing with a much larger dataset and existing backup:
[MySQL Upgrade Method](https://serverfault.com/questions/102485/mysql-upgrade-method))

Answer (score 0):

In many cases binary upgrade will work, however in some cases dump and reload is necessary. 
Here listed some cases: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/checking-table-incompatibilities.html

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that was asked. The poster wants to know which method to use, because he/she already knows that it's required in this instance.